# LaTeX problem with International Journal of Communication Systems

Tags: undefined

I am writing a paper for `International Journal of Communication Systems`. Unfortunately the latex for this journal has a problem which I could not handle it (see the [release](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/(ISSN)1099-1131/homepage/la_tex_class_file.htm) files).

[image]

I even sent them this problem, however they did not respond.

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non-)working example? As the class file loads `caption`, it *should* be perfectly defined, unless youdo not have caption installed on your system.

Comment: First of all, welcome to TeX.SX! My first guess would be that you have an old TeX distribution. What is it?

Comment: Thank you dear @egreg ,
Firstly, please test this release of International Journal yourself because I have sent that to some of my friends and they have this problem too.
Secondly, I am using {WinEdit 5 (v. 5.4) + MikTeX + GSview4.1 + AFPL Ghostscript Fonts + AFPL Ghostscript 7.03}
If it is old please tell me where can I download full package of latex and which program should there exist in this package ?

Comment: Dear @Bernard How can I install caption? Is this a program?

Comment: The current version of [WinEdt](http://www.winedt.com/) is 10.0; if you're still using version 5.4, you may find it well worth your while to perform an update. Which version of [MiKTeX](https://miktex.org/) do you use, incidentally? When did you last run an update using the MiKTeX Package Manager utility?

Comment: The TeX distribution on my system is MacTeX2016. I downloaded the files `dacauth.cls` document class file and tried to compile the `dacauth.tex` demo file. The only change I had to make in the demo file in order to get it to compile was to remove the option `dvips` from the list of options passed to the `hyperref` package. (Cf. line 7 of the code.) I didn't run into any `caption`-related problems, though. This suggests that parts of your TeX distribution are in need of being updated.

Comment: @Mico: Latest version is `10.1`, and the author is working on 10.2

Comment: @Hosein Aqajani: `caption` is a latex package, and you can check if it is installed, and install it if it's not,  with MiKTeX Package Manager (MPM), preferably as Administrator. If youtr version of MiKTeX is < 2.9, you probably had better install the latest.  As to WinEdt, I think you should install the latest version, as it has many, many new features and facilities. It's now a full unicode editor, with bidirectional capabilities.